# Laravel 4, cannot access value in array of objects

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, laravel-4

I am using Laravel 4.2 and thujohn/twitter-l4 to access the twitter API.

I have this code which works when I access it directly:

```
$timeline = Twitter::getUserTimeline(array('screen_name' => $username,
                'count' => 0,
                'include_rts' => false,
                'contributor_details' => false,
                'exclude_replies' => false
      ));
```

I can then do `dd($timeline)`, and see an array that has everything I need:

```
    array (size=20)
  0 => 
    object(stdClass)[145]
      public 'created_at' => string 'Fri Aug 08 12:38:15 +0000 2014' (length=30)
      public 'id' => int 497723464770269184
      public 'id_str' => string '497723464770269184' (length=18)
      public 'text' => string '@crashplan I am trying to turn off 'Automatically renew subscriptions' on web interface. Won't turn off.' (length=104)
      public 'source' => string '<a href="http://twitter.com" rel="nofollow">Twitter Web Client</a>' (length=66)
      public 'truncated' => boolean false
      public 'in_reply_to_status_id' => null
      public 'in_reply_to_status_id_str' => null
      public 'in_reply_to_user_id' => int 13753352
      public 'in_reply_to_user_id_str' => string '13753352' (length=8)
      public 'in_reply_to_screen_name' => string 'crashplan' (length=9)
      public 'user' => 
        object(stdClass)[146]
          public 'id' => int 14569524
          public 'id_str' => string '14569524' (length=8)
          public 'name' => string 'William Macdonald' (length=17)
          public 'screen_name' => string 'wmacdonald' (length=10)
          public 'location' => string 'Stockholm' (length=9)
          public 'description' => string 'William Macdonald Android/iPhone/PHP/Wordpress Developer and entrepreneur living in Stockholm.' (length=94)
          public 'url' => string 'http://t.co/lCnnv3wMmc' (length=22)
          public 'entities' => 
            object(stdClass)[147]
              ...
          public 'protected' => boolean false
          public 'followers_count' => int 164
          public 'friends_count' => int 253
          public 'listed_count' => int 11
```

I can then use: `$friends = $timeline[0]->user->friends_count;` to get the numbers I want.

However when I try and use jQuery to get this same result **Laravel** crashes at the line, `$friends = $timeline[0]->user->friends_count`.

The error message in the laravel.log, pointing to the same line of code:

> Cannot use object of type stdClass as array

I don't see how the exact same piece of code can produce different results when called the same way.

I am using MAMP & PHP 5.5.10 on Mac.

Comment: If you want to get an entry from only one row, use `first()` instead of `get()`.

Comment: The jQuery way is returning a `stdClass` object, not an array. So maybe `$timeline->user->friends_count;` is all you need there. Can you include what the `dd($timeline)` looks like for the jQuery one